# Does $C_0(X)$ completely determine $X$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, banach-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be compact metric spaces. Let $C_0(X)$ and $C_0(Y)$ be the Banach spaces of continuous real-valued functions over $X$ and $Y$, respectively. If $F : X \rightarrow Y$ is a homeomorphism, then $f\mapsto f\circ F$ is an isomorphism from $C_0(Y)$ to $C_0(X)$. Now suppose conversely that $C_0(X)$ and $C_0(Y)$ are isomorphic as Banach spaces. Are $X$ and $Y$ homeomorphic?

What if we replace metric spaces by manifolds and $C_0$ by $C^\infty$?

Comment: You only need compact Hausdorff. This is also true for second-countable smooth manifolds, I think.

Comment: @Jason: sorry, by "this" I meant the version of the question in the last sentence with $C$ replaced by $C^{\infty}$.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "isomorphic as Banach spaces"?  Should there be a bijective isometry between them, or only a linear homeomorphism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the smooth case, you definitely need to know $C^\infty$, as there are examples of compact smooth manifolds which are homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic.

On the other hand $C^\infty(M)$ *does* determine $M$.

Here's the sketch of the proof, which is essentially outlined in the early exercises to Milnor and Stasheff's Characteristic Classes book.

1. For each $x\in M$, define $ev_x:C^\infty(M)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $ev_x(f) = f(x)$ - it evaluates $f$ at the point $x$.  Prove this is a surjective ring homomorphism onto a field, hence the kernel is a maximal ideal of $M$.
2. Show that, in fact, every maximal ideal of $M$ is of the form $\ker(ev_x)$ for some $x\in M$.  (This part is no longer true in the noncompact setting.  For example, the collection of smooth compactly supported functions forms a maximal ideal which is not of this form.)
3. Given a ring isomorphism $\phi:C^\infty(M)\rightarrow C^\infty(N)$, note that $\phi$ must take maximal ideals in $C^\infty (M)$ to maximal ideals in $C^\infty (N)$.  Use this to define $f: M\rightarrow N$ by $ev_{f(x)} \circ \phi = ev_x$.  To see $f$ is smooth, notice that this equation gives that for any $g\in C^\infty(M)$, we have $g(x) = (\phi(g)\circ f)(x)$.  It follows that the composition of $f$ with any function in $C^\infty(N)$ is smooth, in particular with local coordinate functions (extended to the whole of $N$ using a partition of unity).

Comment: I'm not familiar with any proofs of the Banach-Stone theorem (indeed, I'm only vaguely aware of the theorem itself.)  As such, I'm not sure how close this proofs models one which proves Banach-Stone.

Comment: My understanding is that in the noncompact case step 2) should be replaced by "show that every maximal ideal $M$ with residue field $\mathbb{R}$..." although I haven't worked through the details. The proof of the compact Hausdorff version has essentially the same outline (the main technical result needed is Urysohn's lemma).

Answer (score 3):

See [Banach-Stone theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Stone_theorem) for desription of isometric isomorphisms of $C_0$ spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Isomorphism of $C(X)$ and $C(Y)$ does not mean that $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic.  Easy example: $X  = [0,1]$, $Y= X \cup \{2\}$.
The Banach Stone theorems says that $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic if $C(X)$ and $C(Y)$ are isometric. ($X, Y$ compact Hausdorff.)

Comment: What's an example of a isomorphism between $C(X)$ and $C(Y)$?

Comment: $C[0,1]$ contains a complemented copy of $c_0$.  Write $C[0,1] = Z\oplus c_0 = Z\oplus (c_0 \oplus \mathbb{R}) = (Z\oplus c_0) \oplus \mathbb{R} = C[0,1]\oplus \mathbb{R} = C([0,1]\cup \{2\})$.  [$=$ in the sense of isomorphism.]